# $p$-Sylow of odd order contained in the center of a Dedekind group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite Dedekind group. Let $p$ be an odd prime dividing the order of $G$. Call $P$ its $p$-Sylow. Is it true that $P$ is contained in the centre of $G$?

EDIT (solution): if $G$ is abelian i have no problems since $Z(G)=G$. If $G$ is not abelian, by the structure theorem for Dedekind groups i have that $G$ is isomorphic to the direct product of $Q_8$ and an abelian group. Since in my hypothesis $P$ has odd order, then it must be contained in the abelian group of such a direct product, i.e. $P$ is contained in the center of $G$. I think it works.